# Implicit derivative for taylor polynomial

Tags: real-analysis

I have trouble finding implicit derivatives.

$F(x,y,z) = xy+z^3+z-1$

I already know, that there is a solution $z$ for every $(x,y) \in \mathbb{R}^2$. Now I want to find the second order Taylor polynomial of my implicit function $g(x,y) = z$ in $(1,1)$.
I know that $\partial_x g(x,y) = -\frac{\partial_x F(x,y,g(x,y))}{\partial_z F(x,y,g(x,y))}$, for example. But how do I calculate this derivative exactly?
Is it

$\partial_x g(x,y) = -\frac{y}{3g(x,y)^2+1}$

or

$\partial_x g(x,y) = -\frac{y+3g(x,y)^2\partial_xg(x,y)+\partial_xg(x,y)}{3g(x,y)^2+1}$.

Or are both completely wrong?

Comment: How can you solve for $z$ when there’s no equation?

Comment: I was confused, too. But my script states an example as follows:
Let's solve $f(x,y,z)=0$ for $y$ through an implicit function $g$.
Then we have to find the derivative of $f(x,g(x,z),z)=0$ for x. The following notation applies from now on $f_x:=\partial_x f$ and so on.
$f_x(x,g(x,z),z)+f_y(x,g(x,z),z)g_x(x,z)=0 \Leftrightarrow g_x = -\frac{f_x}{f_y}$